# How to dualboot Ubuntu and Windows (as default) with minimal delay on boot?

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10, ssd, bootloader, windows-10

I know there are some other questions here similar to mine, but i think my problem is a little bit different.

So I currently have Windows 10 as my only OS, and I want to install Ubuntu on dual boot; and (at least for now) Windows will be my main OS, so it will be the default option on the boot.
But I have an SSD, and I'm not willing to slow my booting time (for example with a prompt to choose the OS). I know that with grub, it is possible the hide that prompt, and set the delay to zero, and only show it when a certain key is pressed.

That seemed to be a reasonable solution but while I was searching for solutions, I also got the idea that if the default OS is going to be Windows, it doesn't seem logic to use Grub (a linux bootloader) and then it would pass the boot control to the Windows bootloader. That is since most of the times (at least for now) I will be using Windows it would make no sense to first deliver the control to the linux bootloader, and then have it delivered to the windows bootloader; because that would introduce a certain delay in the process.

Can someone, please, confirm me this? And if possible guide me through the best (most optimized) solution for with case: dualboot Windows 10/Ubuntu, with windows as default, and minizing the booting time (so that it changes the least from where it currently is) and if possible with no prompt (unless a given action - like pressing a key - was taken). 
Please refer the bootloader you would use (Windows, Grub, I've got the impression that there are more, ...), as well as a brief strategy (could be a simple link to a good tutorial) of that to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Grub can boot Windows as default, even if it means passing the process to the Windows bootloader. Not sure what's not logical or makes no sense.

Comment: I know Grub can boot windows. The point was (from what i understood): having a bootloader pass the control to another booloader so that the last one could boot windows. Instead of having a single bootloader loading the OS.

Comment: @ubuntuNewbie. that's the way grub2 works and a slight delay is okay according to me.I too have HP latop with SSD only with Windows 10 and Ubuntu15.10 Desktop. I am fine with this slight delay. May be you need to write the custom bootloader to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Is system UEFI or older BIOS? If UEFI you can set UEFI default to Windows and use one time boot key often f10 or f12 to choose Ubuntu/grub when desired. If you have more than one drive with BIOS you can also have Windows boot loader in one drive and grub boot loader in other drive, or even flash drive.

Comment: It's a legacy BIOS. Not UEFI.
So i'm assuming that is not possible on legacy BIOS right? But good to know that info for future.